# SQL : column having occasional NULL value inside AND clause

Tags: sql

Below is a part of a large query in which iam facing the issue.

```
SELECT metricname,careertrackid
FROM atp_9375_forecast
WHERE ibfcollectionid = vspforecasts.ibfid
  AND   atp_9375_forecast.atpclclg = atp_9375_cl.careerlevelcode
  AND   (YEAR>= 2018 AND MONTH>=7)
```

The problem i am facing is in the second AND clause. The MONTH column sometimes is NULL and hence the query is not returning correct result.

I need to handle the NULL values in MONTH clause.

I broke this AND condition and tried something like below but this didn't work.

```
AND   YEAR>= 2018 
 AND MONTH is not null 
 AND Month>=7
```

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct (in most databases).  It has undefined table aliases.  You also need to explain what the "correct result" is.

Comment: `AND Month>=7` is the same as `AND MONTH is not null AND Month>=7`

Comment: the problem is that MONTH column is null in some rows, in that case i need to exclude this column from AND clause

Comment: `AND Month>=7` will exclude rows where `month` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic:

```
WHERE . . . AND  
      (YEAR >= 2018 AND MONTH >= 7)
```

is equivalent to:

```
WHERE . . . AND  
      (YEAR >= 2018 AND MONTH >= 7 AND MONTH IS NOT NULL)
```

If you want to include `NULL` months, then:

```
WHERE . . . AND  
      (YEAR >= 2018 AND (MONTH >= 7 OR MONTH IS NOT NULL))
```

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't work. When MONTH is not null, its fine the comparison happens and gets evaluated. But when MONTH comes as NULL, the comparison fails hence i want to excluse NULL values in MONTH

Comment: @user3205921 . . . (1) Your original code excludes `NULL` values.  (2) That is what this answer explains.